# Remove the menu camera scan, Zxing

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

How can I use the camera scanner ZXing, and not appear menu (sharing, history, using parameters, has about)
I'm applying appleler ZXing via IntentIntegrator.java and IntentResult.java
if it is not possible, is what I am allowed to integrate any application in my project to simply remove this menu?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Well,its quite obvious when You are calling the camera scanner ZXing through intent,the menu would be shown and there is nothing you can do about it,because it is an external app.

So, u have to integrate the zxing scanner into your app for that check out this link

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

and do the changes in the CaptureActivitiy.java file to disable the option menu.

Comment: is that it is legal to do that? because my application will be marketed

Comment: its not about the application being illegal,its actually about respecting the Zxing Open Source..
How would you like it if some guy takes away your application and just copies it into his..??

Comment: Im sure instead of copying the whole thing and disabling the menu you should try to work in through the code,learn and build it for your own sake and for the open source community.

Comment: Sean Owen one of the developers has also commented on this blog...go through his comments and then you will know whether to continue in this way or not...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding the library menu in this case you have to created a menu called **capture.xml** and leave it blank and you will never find the menu anymore.